# Get nth previous working date in MySQL

Tags: mysql

How do I get the nth previous working date in MySQL?
Suppose the function signature is
nth_previous_working_date (d DATE, n INT)

For 10th September, 2015, the function should return 3rd September, 2015

Comment: Check `date_sub()` function in mysql

Comment: what does working date mean? What if they were sick on Tuesday ?

Comment: ^ i think it does not undersatnd about "working" days :)

Comment: Maybe where he comes from he only works 1 day a week, since it seems he just takes the date from 1 week ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `date_sub` function.

```
SELECT DATE_SUB('2015-09-10', INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

or simply use the minus operator

```
SELECT '2015-09-10' - INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

[See the working example.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b65228/1)

Answer (score 0):

Getting the previous non-weekend working day can be done with a case.

```
select case dayofweek(curdate() - interval 1 day) -- yesterday
when 1 then curdate() - interval 3 day -- when sunday, go 2 more days before
when 7 then curdate() - interval 2 day -- when saturday, go 1 more days before
else curdate() - interval 1 day -- yesterday
end
```